Why isn't xlPasteFormat carrying conditional formatting to new workbook?
I"m trying to take a workbook with formulas for calculation and export it to a workbook that is value only. The use case is a scorecard for different items, so having the overall scores color coded to their value in relation to their goal is the need. I have it run on conditional formatting in my calculation workbook, but I want to keep the conditional formatting that is set up when I export to a new value only workbook. xlPasteFormats isn't taking conditional formatting.
'Loop through sheets in a workbook, offset by sheetsToSkip parameter and copy VALUES to a new workbook.
        With wbUpdated
    
            For i = (sheetsToSkip + 1) To wbUpdated.Worksheets.Count
                If wbUpdated.Worksheets(i).Visible = True Then
                    wb.Worksheets.Add After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
                    wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count).Name = .Worksheets(i).Name
                    .Worksheets(i).Cells.Copy
                    wb.Worksheets(i - 1).Activate
                    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:04 AM#
                    wb.Worksheets(i - 1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .Worksheets(i).Cells.Copy
                    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:04 AM#
                    wb.Worksheets(i - 1).Activate
                    wb.Worksheets(i - 1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    
                ' Set the column widths to be the same
                    For j = .Worksheets(i).Range("A1").Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                        If wb.Worksheets(i - 1).Range("A1").Columns(j).ColumnWidth <> .Worksheets(i).Range("A1").Columns(j).ColumnWidth Then
                            wb.Worksheets(i - 1).Range("A1").Columns(j).ColumnWidth = .Worksheets(i).Range("A1").Columns(j).ColumnWidth
                        End If
                    Next
                Else
                End If
            Next i
            
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            

        End With
    

I've tried xlPasteFormats, xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats (This gives a 1004 error. I have yet to figure out why), and xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats. Nothing seems to work. I would like to find a holistic solution to this, but if I need to copy properties range by range, it isn't the end of the world because only 3 columns have formatting that I would like to move over.
I'm currently on Windows 11 with Excel 365.I put the application wait lines in because I thought Excel was going too fast for its own good, but that didn't resolve the issue obviously.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
